# how to download an element created by the user and give it an event?

Tags: javascript

how to download an element created by the user and give it an event?

```
function tasks(e) {
    inputV = input.value;
    e.preventDefault();
    if (inputV !== "") {
        const ul = document.querySelector('.tasks-list');
        let li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML += inputV /*`<button class="deleteTasks">Usuń</button>`*/;
        ul.appendChild(li);
        let btnDell = document.createElement('button');
        btnDell.setAttribute("id", "deleteTasks");
        btnDell.innerHTML += 'usuń';
        li.appendChild(btnDell);
        input.value = "";
    }
};
add.addEventListener('click', tasks);
```

Comment: What do you mean by download ?

Comment: it is a vague question. what do you mean by downloading an element?

Comment: i wents to event on btnDell to remove this button and li

Answer (score 0):

If I get it well you want your btnDell to delete the li element. You should use something like on the button click

```
function removeParent(e){
   e.parentNode.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After creation of new list Element, you can attach your custom event handler.

```
function tasks(e) {
    inputV = input.value;
    e.preventDefault();
    if (inputV !== "") {
        const ul = document.querySelector('.tasks-list');
        let li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML += inputV /*`<button class="deleteTasks">Usuń</button>`*/;
        let node = ul.appendChild(li).cloneNode(true);
        node.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
            e.preventDefault();
            let target = e.target;
            // put your logic here to execut on target after it being clicked
        },false); 
        let btnDell = document.createElement('button');
        btnDell.setAttribute("id", "deleteTasks");
        btnDell.innerHTML += 'usuń';
        li.appendChild(btnDell);
        input.value = "";
    }
};
add.addEventListener('click', tasks);
```

**Edit**  I am editing this after reading your comment, please edit your question instead of put a comment to clarify your question. My assumption was that you want this functionality.

But it seems you'r logic on delete don't get execute on newly created items, if that's the case try to set a class property on each deletable `li` and write btnDell base on `querySelectorAll` that get all the elements at the time it's getting execute.